# How to find the Big O for this algorithm, if it’s polynomial, P = NP

Tags: javascript, algorithm, np

I would like to find if this algorithm is polynomial. It’s a solution to Partition Problem. As you might know, if is polynomial, P = NP.

The algorithm is:

```
///// Partition Problem Algorithm

var set = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];
var setCopy = set;
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
var setSum = 0;
var found = 0;
var sumNumbers = [];
var setLength = set.length;
var storeNumber = [];

while (found < 1) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * set.length); /// generate a random number
    sum += set[random]; /// take a random number from set
    if (sumNumbers == 0) { /// if doesn’t have a number in array
        sumNumbers += set[random]; /// stores the number without a comma
    } else {
        sumNumbers += [", " + set[random]]; /// stores the number with a comma
    }
    console.log(sumNumbers); /// show the number
    set.splice(random, 1); /// takes the number of set
    for (j = 0; j < set.length; j++) {
        setSum = setSum + set[j]; /// sum all numbers of set
    }
    if (sum == setSum) { /// if the sum of the numbers of a set is equal to the other
        console.log("Found!");
        console.log("First Set: " + sum, "Second Set: " + setSum);
        console.log(sumNumbers);
        console.log(set); /// show the set
        found++; /// count a point to the found
    } else {
        console.log("Not Found");
        console.log("First Set: " + sum, "Second Set: " + setSum);
        if (sum > setSum) {
            sum = 0;
            var set = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];
            setSum = 0;
            sumNumbers = 0;
            console.log("New attempt");
        }
    }
    var setSum = 0 /// turn the sum of all number of the set to zero, because of the while loop
}
```

In order to fix the algorithm for a deterministic algorithm, by suggestion of cobarzan:

```
    ///// Partition Problem Algorithm

var set = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];
var setCopy = set;
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
var setSum = 0;
var found = 0;
var sumNumbers = [];
var setLength = set.length;
var storeNumber = [];

while (found < 1) {
    var takeOne = 0; /// take the first number
    sum += set[takeOne]; /// take a the number from set
    if (sumNumbers == 0) { /// if doesn’t have a number in array
        sumNumbers += set[takeOne]; /// stores the number without a comma
    } else {
        sumNumbers += [", " + set[takeOne]]; /// stores the number with a comma
    }
    console.log(sumNumbers); /// show the number
    set.splice(takeOne, 1); /// takes the number of set
    for (j = 0; j < set.length; j++) {
        setSum = setSum + set[j]; /// sum all numbers of set
    }
    if (sum == setSum) { /// if the sum of the numbers of a set is equal to the other
        console.log("Found!");
        console.log("First Set: " + sum, "Second Set: " + setSum);
        console.log(sumNumbers);
        console.log(set); /// show the set
        found++; /// count a point to the found
    } else {
        console.log("Not Found");
        console.log("First Set: " + sum, "Second Set: " + setSum);
        if (sum > setSum) {
            sum = 0;
            var set = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1];
            setSum = 0;
            sumNumbers = 0;
            takeOne++
            console.log("New attempt");
            if (takeOne == set.length) {
                var takeOne += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    var setSum = 0 /// turn the sum of all number of the set to zero, because of the while loop
}
```

Comment: By definition, **P** "contains all decision problems that can be solved by a **deterministic** Turing machine using a polynomial amount of computation time, or polynomial time." [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity))]. So using **random** stuff takes **P** of the table.

Comment: @cobarzan Even if that algorithm worked in randomized polynomial time that would be a major breakthrough.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, cobarzan. Then, with this new version, could be right? Thanks again!

Comment: "if it’s polynomial, P = NP" - then it's *not*...

Comment: It's not polynomial time? Or do I wrote wrong? :)

Answer (score 4):

If there is only one possible partition, then this approach will take an exponential amount of time on average before finding it.  So it would have exponential running time.

If there is no possible partition, this approach will NEVER produce an answer, and so you'll NEVER get a decision.  You therefore do not have a program that solves the decision problem of saying whether or not such an answer exists in finite time.

In reality the limitations of pseudo-random number generators are such that if there are very few solutions for a decent sized set, you will NEVER find the answer because there are only so many things you can try before it starts looping.

This is therefore strictly worse than the naive exponential brute-force search.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So, the algorithm is exponential, because of the pseudo-random generator? Also, I've included a "notFound" variable, in a old version, this could be better? And the algorithm is exponential, right? This is worse than polynomial, right? Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: And sorry to bother you, but have you saw both algorithms? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I do have an algorithm, which I believe too to be in polynomial time, but I think it's not *beautiful*. It's the integer factorization algorithm, should I publish? Thanks for your comprehension. Because I factored a 233 digit number in a normal computer...

Comment: The algorithm is exponential because it does nothing more than try random guesses until it finds the right one.  There are an exponential number of guesses.

As for factorization, there are a lot of factorization algorithms that will factor random 233 digit numbers on a personal computer very quickly.  Factoring hard ones is a different story.  Can you factor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768 ?

Comment: Yes, in fact, in this question, I tell that I factored a 233-digit number, and RSA-240!

Comment: And user448810 said that it would be good publishing, what do you think?

Comment: (This question:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191720/does-publishing-a-polynomial-time-tentative-of-integer-factorization-algorithm-w

Comment: The factors are 5.170923996658113e+215 * 1952999886528199. I’ve published the algorithm in another question, help me there.

Comment: @AlexKenjiTakegawa RSA-232 divided by 1952999886528199 has remainder 1503258066774864 and so that is not a factor.  Perhaps you should learn more about big integer arithmetic before tackling problems like this?

Comment: But if you divide RSA-232 by 5.170923996658113e+215, gives 1952999886528199. Thanks

Comment: If you are using an integer representation with `e+215` in it then you are doing a floating point calculation, NOT integer calculations.  Which means that your program is dealing with approximate numbers, and not exact ones.  But factoring requires exact numbers.  This is why I said that you need to learn more about big integer arithmetic.

Comment: Suppose that this algorithm was ported to python, which I believe to have support to whole number, without scientific notation. This would satisfy the condition? Also, do exist an method to display the whole number in JS? Thanks!